# copy mysql db from previous xampp to new one

Tags: mysql, xampp

I reinstalled my computer, before I did that, I copy my Xampp folder for backup.

the problem is i forget to backup my database from Phpmyadmin.

I tried to copy `/xampp/mysql/data/` to new one but i got error

```
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

anyone how to fix this?

*browser is ok to access those data, but i have trouble to open it inside of phpmyadmin

Comment: Try executing `phpmyadmin/sql/create_tables.sql` to recreate phpmyadmin tables.

Comment: You need to copy the .frm and the ib_logfiles and ibdata file into your data folder. and just restart the Xampp and you database is restored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, run a linux live cd and copy the xampp folder into your external drive then go to the target computer, run again live cd on the target computer or just boot it in safe mode(for windows) then copy the xampp folder into your target computers drive.